# I get a `cannot open camera "0" without camera permission` Error when I try to open a camera to scan a QR code

Tags: flutter, dart

I get a `cannot open camera "0" without camera permission` Error when I try to open a camera to scan a QR code.

I have a QR code scanner function  that does not open the camera. The scanner screen appears but I do not see the box with the line inside for scanning.

I have also added camera permissions in the Android manifest

Android Manifest Permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The Scanner Function is below

```
Future <void> scanqr() async {
      final qrCode = await scanner.scan();
     
        setState(() {
          this.qrCode = qrCode;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//use permission_handler package and use the below code.. it will work fine

```
Future <void> scanqr() async {
          await Permission.camera.request();
          final qrCode = await scanner.scan();
            setState(() {
              this.qrCode = qrCode;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).